# $(this) doesn't work in angularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am making a chrome extension with angularJS, now I have a problem.

I want add some button in my popup page, and I want when button is clicked, it's ancestor node disappear, here's my code.

in popup.html

```
<div class="deadline">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="removeDeadline()">complete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

in controller.js

```
$scope.removeDeadline = function(){
  $(this).closest(".deadline").remove();
}
```

I don't know why that doesn't work.
Please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, `$` is a jQuery function--did you include jQuery in your extension? If not, `angular.element` is the function for the built-in "jQuery Lite" that AngularJS ships with.

Secondly, accessing a DOM element from inside a controller action is incorrect form when using AngularJS: Angular is all about views that automatically reflect the state of models (via the `$scope`). For example, the snippet you showed would be more properly written as:

```html
<div class="deadline" ng-hide="hideLine">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="removeDeadline()">complete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```javascript
$scope.removeDeadline = function(){
  $scope.hideLine = true;
}
```

Take this quote from [the FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) to heart:

> Stop trying to use jQuery to modify the DOM in controllers. Really. That includes adding elements, removing elements, retrieving their contents, showing and hiding them. Use built-in directives, or write your own where necessary, to do your DOM manipulation. See below about duplicating functionality.
>
> If you're struggling to break the habit, consider removing jQuery from your app. Really. Angular has the $http service and powerful directives that make it almost always unnecessary. Angular's bundled jQLite has a handful of the features most commonly used in writing Angular directives, especially binding to events.

Comment: Thank you, but I have multiple .deadline in my html, how can i only remove it which i click on?

Comment: Removing jQuery from the app is what really helped me get over the jQuery way of doing things (especially in controllers).. Great advice.

Comment: @user1926122 You would have a different variable for each, or an object or array, etc. With Angular, focus first on your data model, and then wire up your view to the model. Everything should focus on the data model.